# Flow formula CONTAINS fails to find matching text

Tags: visual-workflow, formula

Simple use case

- Before Save Flow on Case.
- Formula Boolean element `hasMarkerInSubject` defined as:

  ```
  CONTAINS({!Record.Subject},'Foo')
  ```
- when presented in Debug with a Case with Subject = `blahblahFooblahblah`
- Returns FALSE

Formula doc on CONTAINS says it is Case Sensitive but I've got a perfect match. Why does the formula return FALSE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Not so simple to figure this one out no matter how many experiments one performs in the Flow Debugger.  You can modify the formula and the input data until the cows come home and you will get no clues (at least as of V55)*

I pasted the equivalent formula into a custom field on `Case` object

```
CONTAINS(Subject,'Foo')
```

and, *le voilà!*, the Custom Field formula dialog pops up this error:

```
Error: You referenced an unsupported field type called 
       "Text (Encrypted)" using the following field: CONTAINS
```

And yes, the Org has Shield Encryption on Case.Subject. [Most formula functions do not work on Shield-encrypted fields](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_pe_formulas.htm&type=5) - especially any formula that does string operations like `CONTAINS`, `MID`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, ...

Apparently, the Flow Save validation checks don't look for Shield violations and you are left questioning your competence.

**Workarounds**:

- Escape to Apex via an invocable action (not possible in Before Save flows)
- Use Apex before insert/update trigger